# Calculate query coverage from BLAST output

Tags: python, regex, linux, csv, bioinformatics

I have a [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) output file and want to calculate query coverage, appending the query lengths as an additional column to the output.  Let's say I have

```
2 7 15
```

```
f=open('file.txt', 'r')
lines=f.readlines()
import re 
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
    q_start=new_list[0]
    q_end=new_list[1]
    q_len=new_list[3]
    q_cov=((float(q_end)-float(q_start))/float(q_len))*100
    q_cov=round(q_cov,1)
    q_cov=str(q_cov) 
    new_list.append(q_cov)
    r=open('results.txt', 'a')
    x='\t'.join(new_list)
    x=x+'\n'
    r.writelines(x)
f.close()
r.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One serious bug is that you open `results.txt` for each line of input.  It's almost always better to [open files in a `with` block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283052/1157100).  Then, you won't have to worry about closing your filehandles, even if the code exits abnormally.  The `with` block would have made your `results.txt` mistake obvious as well.

Since you want to treat your `q_start`, `q_end`, and `q_len` as numbers, I wouldn't even bother to assign their string representations to a variable.  Just convert them to a `float` as soon as possible.  Similarly, `q_cov` should be a `float`; I would just stringify it at the last moment.  I would also postpone rounding just for the purposes of formatting the output, preferring to preserve precision in `q_cov` itself.

Put your `import` statements at the beginning of the program.

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as input, open('results.txt', 'a') as output:
    for line in input.readlines():
        fields = re.split(r'\t+', line.strip())
        q_start, q_end, q_len = map(float, (fields[0], fields[1], fields[3]))
        q_cov = 100 * (q_end - q_start) / q_len
        print >>output, '\t'.join(fields + [str(round(q_cov, 1))])
```

Comment: ++ for with block